# Search dataframe across two tables and replace value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to search with a string in a pandas dataframe A, compare it with another dataframe B and write the value from another column of that dataframe B into the original column in dataframe A.
Like:

Table_a:

| fruit | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| apple | red |
| banana | yellow |
| orange | orange |

Table_b:

| fruit | size | abbrev. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | large | app. |
| orange | medium | oran. |
| peach | small | pea. |
| banana | medium | ban. |

So the modified table_a shall be:

| fruit | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| apple | app. |
| banana | ban. |
| orange | ora. |

How can I search across two dataframes and replace with a specific column from df_b?

This has been my non-working approach so far.
Can you help, pls?

```py
table_a["attribute"] = table_a.loc[table_a["fruit"] == table_b["fruit"], table_b["attribute"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Thanks, but not really. The order can be mixed up in my scenario. So I need something like: take: table_a["fruit"], search with that value in table_b["fruit"], return the appropriate ["abbreviation"]-value and write it in table_a["attribute"].

Comment: You're describing a merge.

Comment: `table_a[['fruit']].merge(table_b[['fruit','abbrev.']].rename({'abrev.':'attribute'}), on='fruit', how='left')`

Comment: Thanks @Chris Unfortunately that does not work, cuz it says: KeyError: 'fruit'. Isn't there a "search and replace"-way instead of merging?

Comment: You must not have fruit columns in both dataframes

Comment: you are right. my bad ;) thank you again. that helped, even though it's a little detour.